# Массив из Geneiric`ов

Tags: swift, swift4

Запутался с Дженеривками ... Ниже привожу пример кода (врезал только существенное для плейграунда):

```
 import UIKit

protocol MyElement_Protocol {
    associatedtype myType
    var value: myType! { get }
}

class MyAbstractClass<myType>: MyElement_Protocol {
    var value: myType!
}

class MyFirstClass : MyAbstractClass<Int> {

}

class MySecondClass : MyAbstractClass<[MyAbstractClass<Any>]> {
    func loadFromFile() {
        value.append(MyFirstClass())

    }

}
```

У меня есть протокол (**MyElement_Protocol** ), который определяет функционал некоторых классов ...
далее я делаю **MyAbstractClass**, в котором реализую "общий" функционал 
для всех объектов. Далее вне нужно сделать несколько классов , часть из которых базируются на простых типах типа String  или Int (в примере **MyFirstCLass**) и часть является массивом самих этих объектов 
в примере **MySecondClass : MyAbstractClass<[MyAbstractClass]>** ...

в функции **value.append(MyFirstClass())** xCode выдает ошибку

> Cannot convert value of type 'MyAbstractClass' to expected
>   argument type 'MyAbstractClass'

Как правильно записать этот кусок кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
class MySecondClass : MyAbstractClass<[MyElement_Protocol]> {
    func loadFromFile() {
        value = []
        value.append(MyFirstClass())
    }
}
```

**Дополнение**

Согласно комментарию метод `add` можно реализовать так

```
import UIKit

protocol MyElement_Protocol {
    associatedtype myType
    var value: myType! { get }
}

class MyAbstractClass<myType>: MyElement_Protocol {
    var value: myType!
}

class MyFirstClass : MyAbstractClass<Int> {

}

class MySecondClass : MyAbstractClass<[MyElement_Protocol]> {
    func loadFromFile() {
        value = []
        value.append(MyFirstClass())
    }

    func add<T: MyElement_Protocol>(obj : T)  {
        if value == nil {
            value = []
        }

        value.append(obj)
    }

    func add<T: MyElement_Protocol>(obj : [T])  {
        if value == nil {
            value = []
        }

        value.append(contentsOf: obj)
    }
}

let mFC = MyFirstClass()
let mSC = MySecondClass()
mSC.add(obj: mFC)
```

Comment: не. .. не получается, хотя по началу вроде все норм ... при создании конструктора надо указать тип, а тип - [MyElement_Protocol] - Protocol 'MyElement_Protocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: @AlexanderDrozdov приведите пример

Comment: @AlexanderDrozdov не могли бы дополнить вопрос примером в виде кода

Comment: В общем проблема при создании нового метода func add(obj : [MyElement_Protocol])  если его объявить так, то компилятор снова ругается на Protocol 'MyElement_Protocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: @AlexanderDrozdov см дополнение

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: Что то не выходит каменный цветок ....   test: let mFC = MyFirstClass(); let mSC = MySecondClass(); mSC.add(obj: mFC) - выдает : Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Comment: @AlexanderDrozdov у меня работает, возможно дело в версии свифта или икскода? Я использую последние версии

Comment: Аналогично  xCode: 11.4.1 , Swift 5 ... просто засада какая-то ...

Comment: @AlexanderDrozdov вы запускаете в точности тот же пример что и я? Посмотрите, я обновил ответ

Comment: Да, действительно ... видимо у меня руки не оттуда растут ... Спасибо! Буду изучать где я косячу ....